# Adding a border dynamically, adds height

Tags: css

Im adding a border to my table row dynamically using JS.

This causes the table to jump down slightly because of the border adding height to the row.

How can I prevent this?

I've tried adding a transparent border, which then gets replaced with the real border.

This works, but I was looking for a better solution, so I tried:

```
box-sizing: border-box
```

This did not work.

What's the best solution to this?

Comment: "I've tried adding a transparent border, which then gets replaced with the real border." I don't see why you don't just use this. It's a common solution.

Comment: I've run into this issue quite a lot, and in my opinion a transparent or background coloured border is the best solution.

Comment: `box-sizing` can only have an effect if you have a specific height set …

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a transparent border (advisable for you to use it, not sure why you wouldnt), you could instead simply give the cell padding of the same amount as your border width, and remove on hover, e.g.

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/cqn0wwex/)

```
td{
    padding:3px;
}
td:hover{
    border:3px solid;
    padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you couldn't spare the padding - and you don't need to support IE8, you could try tinkering with `box-shadow`

```
td:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 3px #111;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/evanbriggs/vbcutxmq/